# Dart / Flutter : How Do I Sign a String Using an ES 256 Algorithm and Private Key

Tags: flutter, dart, digital-signature

Since Flutter doesn't support any map APIs across all platforms (mobile and desktop), I'm trying to fetch map snapshots with Apple's [Web Snapshots API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/snapshots/generating_a_url_and_signature_to_create_a_maps_web_snapshot). This involves constructing a URL with various options then signing the URL. I append the signature to the end of my request URL so Apple can verify that it's from me.

Apple's instructions state:

> *To generate a signature, sign the string with your private key using a ES256 algorithm (also known as ECDSA using P-256 curve and SHA-256 hash algorithm). The signature must be Base64 URL-encoded.*

I don't need to decrypt anything, I just need to sign the string and add it to the end of my request URL. So I don't think I need anything beyond the `crypto` library included with Flutter.

Here's what I've tried:

```dart
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

//Private Key
var key = utf8.encode('''
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
abcdef...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
''');

var bytes = utf8.encode('My URL String to Sign...');

var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, key);
var sig = hmacSha256.convert(bytes);
    
var signature = base64UrlEncode(sig.bytes);
```

I get an unintelligible string as `signature` and add it to my request URL, but I still get a `401 Not Authorized` error, so my signature must be incorrect.

How can I properly sign my URL string with my private key?

Comment: The posted code uses a completely different algorithm (HMAC) than specified (ECDSA = Elliptic Curve DSA). You need a library that supports ECDSA, e.g. PointyCastle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pointycastle, you need a suitable random number generator instance and a signer initialized with the relevant digest. Then just call `generateSignature`.  That only gets you the `r` and `s` values which you need to encode.

Here's an example:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:pointycastle/asn1.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

  // the private key
  ECPrivateKey? privateKey;
  
  // some bytes to sign
  final bytes = Uint8List(0);

  // a suitable random number generator - create it just once and reuse
  final rand = Random.secure();
  final fortunaPrng = FortunaRandom()
    ..seed(KeyParameter(Uint8List.fromList(List<int>.generate(
      32,
      (_) => rand.nextInt(256),
    ))));

  // the ECDSA signer using SHA-256
  final signer = ECDSASigner(SHA256Digest())
    ..init(
      true,
      ParametersWithRandom(
        PrivateKeyParameter(privateKey!),
        fortunaPrng,
      ),
    );

  // sign the bytes
  final ecSignature = signer.generateSignature(bytes) as ECSignature;

  // encode the two signature values in a common format
  // hopefully this is what the server expects
  final encoded = ASN1Sequence(elements: [
    ASN1Integer(ecSignature.r),
    ASN1Integer(ecSignature.s),
  ]).encode();

  // and finally base 64 encode it
  final signature = base64UrlEncode(encoded);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. There's no way in a million years I could have figured that out myself.  I'm unclear on how to convert my private key (a .p8 file with a string inside) to an `ECPrivateKey`, but you've given me a huge boost. Thanks again!

Comment: Use the `basic_utils` package. See: https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils#cryptoutils There's a method `ECPrivateKey ecPrivateKeyFromPem(String pem)`. (I see that there are new utility methods I haven't seen before: `ecSign` and `ecSignatureToBase64`, which perform most of the code above.)

Answer (score 1):

A huge thanks to **Richard Heap** for providing the solution. I just wanted to post the final code I settled on for anyone running into this in the future. Only [the basic_utils package](https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils#cryptoutils) is needed.

```dart
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

final url = 'My URL string...';

//Convert the URL string to Uint8List
final urlBytes = utf8.encode(url) as Uint8List;

//Prep the private key
var key = '''
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
abcdef...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
''');

ECPrivateKey privateKey = CryptoUtils.ecPrivateKeyFromPem(key);

//Sign the URL
ECSignature sig = CryptoUtils.ecSign(privateKey, urlBytes, algorithmName: 'SHA-256/ECDSA');

//Convert signature to Base64
final signature = CryptoUtils.ecSignatureToBase64(sig);
```

I just add that `signature` to the end of the URL string as required by Apple's API and it works great!

Comment: It's probably better to: `final urlBytes = utf8.encode(url) as Uint8List;`

Comment: Getting this Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 48: 48 in ecPrivateKeyFromPem. Please help